# yaml-cpp in ROS2 linking errors

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, yaml-cpp, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

Following problem occurred:
I'm trying to use yaml-cpp in a ROS2 package and it returns loads of linking errors ("undefined reference to ...") I have linked yaml-cpp to the project in the CMakeLists.txt and it throws no errors what so ever, so I assumed everything went fine. Did something change with the yaml-cpp library for ROS2? Or do i have a mistake in my CMakeList?

Important parts of CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)

# include directories
include_directories(
  include
  include/multi_node_controller
  include/multi_node_controller/auto_generated
  ${YAML_CPP_INCLUDEDIR}
)

add_executable(function_parser src/function_parser.cpp)

ament_target_dependencies(function_parser
                          rclcpp
                          std_msgs
                          custom_msgs
                          yaml-cpp)
```

Or do I need to include it in the package.xml?

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333813/yaml-cpp-in-ros2-linking-errors/) by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I figured it out myself. I thought `ament_target_dependencies` invokes `target_link_libraries`, so I thought everything should be as in ROS1, but apparently you need an extra call of  `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})` after the `ament_target_dependencies(...)`.

---

Originally posted by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) with karma: 196 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3